# FQL Event start_time query

Tags: android, facebook

I am using FQL in an Android app to get events

The query runs fine and I get events e.g.

```
{eid":356869247704497,"name":"An event","start_time":1338595200,"end_time":1338606000}
```

I take the start_time and convert to a Java calendar via

```
Calendar occasionDate = Calendar.getInstance();
occasionDate.setTime(new Date(1338595200 * 1000));
Log.d("app", occasionDate.getTime().toString());
```

which produces

Sat Jun 02 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2012

Whereas the date on the FB site is Friday, June 1, 2012 at 5:00pm

So what timezone is the start_time stored in the db?

Answer (score 0):

It says in the return - GMT +1:00. That gives the game away :-)

Comment: GMT + 1 will not make up the difference between the date shown on the FB site and one being returned by the FQL query

Comment: What time zone are you in? You're in California?

Comment: Well, it's translating a if you're in California. It's giving you London (Summer Time) - in the query, bit showing a if you're in Vancouver/California in the site.

Comment: The event was created in the UK, do you know what timezone FB store the date in?